# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 next to Win7 - No boot menu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have installed Windows 7 today and right after installed Ubuntu 12.04 next to it.

Now after rebooting the machine, it goes right into Win7 without asking me anything at the boot menu which OS to load.

In windows I can see that the ubuntu partitions are still there.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you installed the grub? Please let us know about your configuration of disks. Also boot with live usb/cd and install `boot repair` and run it. instruction here-> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Comment: oh dear, it has installed the GRUB on the USb stick where I installed Ubuntu 12.04 from. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the GRUB is installed in usb disk not in your hard disk , I recommend you to boot the live usb, then install `boot-repair` tool and reinstall grub to your hard disk. :)

Read carefully -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: yes that worked thanks. I went with option 2 and installed the app as a package. It is a waste of space right? But at least it works now. Weird, I went with the standard options, why did it install it on the USB disk? a bug?

Comment: I never face such thing. Possibly an unwanted mouse click on installation option did this.